# How to use gorilla websocket and mux in the same application?

Tags: go, gorilla

```golang
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/api", home)
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../public"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", handleConnections)
    go handleMessages()

    log.Println("http server started on :8000")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nill)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

With the above code, the /api route gives a 404.
But if I change the `err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nill)` to `err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)`, the /api route works but the / route (which I serve the frontend) gives a 404.

How do I make them both work?

Edit: full code - https://codeshare.io/2Kpyb8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter type of the `http.ListenAndServe` function is http.Handler, if he is nil, http lib use `http.DefaultServeMux` http.Handler.

your `/api` route register to `mux.NewRouter()`, your `/` and `/ws` route register to `http.DefaultServeMux`,These are two different http.Handler objetc, You need to merge the routing requests registered by the two routers.

```golang
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/api", home)
    // move ws up, prevent '/*' from covering '/ws' in not testing mux, httprouter has this bug.
    router.HandleFunc("/ws", handleConnections)
    // PathPrefix("/") match '/*' request
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("../public")))
    go handleMessages()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
```

[gorilla/mux example](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#examples) not use http.HandleFunc function.

Comment: The "/" route still doesn't work, none of the static files are being served.

Comment: I not use gorilla/mux, uncertain route `/` or `/*` match all request,like `/` can mathc all request uri.

your 404 is file not found, not is route 404. os.Open has no file return 404,Permission denied return 403.  

static file reference https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/net-http-give-404-error-when-trying-to-call-other-route-that-isnt/18296/3?u=eudore

Comment: The following wildcard matching was studied. The correct code is `router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("../public")))`. The mux library is different from other library frameworks. Chaos design interface.

Comment: That causes the websocket connection to fail `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Comment: `/ws` move '/*' up? I modified the original answer

Comment: `/*` route and wildcards route will override other routes in mux and httprouter. `/*` contain `/ws` path, So pay attention to the order of routing registration.